# SAP Hybris Backoffice - advanced search result

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, advanced-search

for BO there is such list:

```
    <context type="Order" component="cs-listview">
        <list:list-view xmlns:list="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/listView">
            <list:column qualifier="code"/>
            <list:column qualifier="user"/>
            <list:column qualifier="date"/>
            <list:column qualifier="deliveryMode" />
            <list:column qualifier="status" />
        </list:list-view>
    </context>
```

After the cancellation order, Hybris creates duplicate order with the same status as it was before the cancellation. So we have 2 orders with 2 statuses.

I'd like to have only 1 entry in result. How it's possible?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H2Mx.png)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in 2 ways.

1. Search Restriction on customersupportagentgroup or related group.

   INSERT_UPDATE SearchRestriction;code[unique=true];principal(uid)[unique=true];query;restrictedType(code)[unique=true];active;generate

   ;backendOrderVisibility;customersupportagentgroup;{versionID} IS NULL;Order;true;true
2. create new Controller to send extra filter which will give result of orders which having version id null, this is part of backoffice customization.
   --->Create custom controller and extend this AbstractInitAdvancedSearchAdapter and override addSearchDataConditions.
   ---->Create definition.xml
   -----> ovverride widget connection as well.